# Difficulty understanding multiple recursive calls

Tags: recursion

```
function max(arr, first, last){
if (first==last) return arr[first];
mid=first+(last-first)/2;
a=max(arr, first,mid);
b=max(arr, mid+1,last);
if (a<b) return b;
return a;
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding this recursive function as I don't really understand how the flow works when assigning the variables. My understanding is that when `a=max(arr, first,mid);` a will keep calling the function until the base case occurs - so I am safe to assume while this is happening

```
b=max(arr, mid+1,last);     
if (a<b) return b;
    return a;`
```

is not executed until 'a' is done calling? And when the flow reaches 'b' and it starts recursivly calling, does it affect `a=max(arr, first,mid);` - in that it will apply different values to a?

My understanding in context to finding the max was that a would find the maximum element in the first half and b would find the maximum element in the second half but I don't understand how it can do that when `if (a<b) return b; return a;` isn't called until at the end when a and b have values, my thought was that it would check this so that it could find the maximum in a and maximum in b and then compare the max of both halves to find the maximum element in arr?

Sorry if the Q is vague I'm just trying to better my understanding of recursion

Comment: The short answer is: `a` will get the max value of the lower half of the array and `b` will get the max value of the upper half of the array and finally the function will return the higher value between `a` and `b`. The overall result is the max value in the array.

Comment: I understand this much as stated in my question I just don't understand the recursive part of it

Comment: To answer your concern regarding the effect of the next statement affecting the previous statement depends on how variable `a` is defined. If `a` is a global variable or a static variable, then it will be affected as the next statement will recurse and set the value of global variable `a`. To prevent such, you have to define `a` and `b` as local variables.

Comment: In shirt, when `a` and `b` are local variables, the values assigned to them are limited to that instance of function call. When `a` and `b` are global variables, their values will be set every single time the function is called (including recursive calls).

Comment: Thanks for addressing that, they are local. How does the function find the max value in a or b though? For example in a, wouldn't it just recursively call itself until it returns it's first element as the base case states, I don't understand when it checks to find the max element in a or b.

Comment: In the statement `a=max(arr, first, mid)`, the function will be called recursively more than once. The last call (deepest call) will return the first element. When it returns to the calling function, the calling function (second to the deepest) will proceed to `b=max(arr,mid+1,last)`. In this instance, the mid+1 is equal to the current last which is the second element. Note that the function has to return back several times to get back to the top function call.

Comment: In short, the first recursion will cut the array in half. The second recursion will cut the half array in half (quarter array). This goes on for every recursion until there is only one element passed to the function. Each of the function call returns the higher value between a and b. Each recursion will have their own a and b.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to understand how it works by following it step by step, chasing every single call all the way down.  Don't do that, it's confusing.

Look at what one call does, without worrying about what happens in functions the current invocation of `max()` calls.  Yes, it calls itself, and even does it twice.  Both of those calls are function calls that return a value, and as far as the current invocation of `max()` is concerned, they might as well just be numbers.

If I replaced the lines assigning `a` and `b` with this:

```
a = 13;
b = 42;
```

then you wouldn't have any trouble understanding what it does.  And if I replaced them with this:

```
a = max_implemented_with_a_for_loop(arr, first, mid);
b = max_implemented_with_a_for_loop(arr, mid+1, last);
```

then you wouldn't have trouble with that either.  The recursive version isn't that different.

Recursive functions like this work by taking a big problem, dividing it into smaller subproblems, solving the subproblems, and combining the solutions to solve the big problem.  It uses itself to solve the subproblems, and if we didn't have base cases, there would be a snag - there comes a point where you can't subdivide the problem any further, and you need another way of solving these tiny subproblems.  But it isn't much of a snag, since a subproblem that's too small to divide anymore is easy to solve.  The base case just notices that we've got something easy to solve directly and/or can't be divided any further, and handles it.

Answer (score 0):

Each recursive call has a smaller non-negative value of last-first. So if the first call has non-negative value of last-first then each call, including the first, terminates.

If last==first then it returns the only element in the range as maximum.

Otherwise it returns the larger of the maximum of the first half (a) and the maximum of the second half (b).

In either case the maximum is correctly calculated, and there are no other cases.